# Dropping duplicates in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider the following dataframe snippet, which has been sorted by Winner_Count.

```
        Year    Award          Winner   Name    Winner_Count    Winner_Pct
9347    2011    Best Actress    1.0 Meryl Streep    19           0.010144
9098    2009    Best Actress    0.0 Meryl Streep    19           0.010144
7483    1995    Best Actress    0.0 Meryl Streep    19           0.010144
6389    1985    Best Actress    0.0 Meryl Streep    19           0.010144
7835    1998    Best Actress    0.0 Meryl Streep    19           0.010144
```

All I want to do is groupby Name, so that I don't have the same actor 19 times in a row (e.g, seeing Meryl, and her Winner_Count, only once would be fine), but the sorted order is preserved. So far, I've gotten various error messages and, on one occasion, an object reference.  I have yet to see a table. Some of the posts I've seen here suggest making a groupby object appear requires considerably more work than, for example, what is shown in Wes McKinney's video, which is strange.

Why is this not a simple `df_new = df.groupby('Name')`? And why won't the object appear automatically when/if a reference appears? I seem to be missing something fundamental about the groupby object and need a correction. Thoughts?

Edit:

The desired data set would look like this: one row for each actor, whereas in the original data set, there would be several.

```
        Year    Award          Winner   Name    Winner_Count    Winner_Pct
9347    2011    Best Actress    1.0 Meryl Streep       19       0.010144
5953    1981    Best Actress    1.0 Katharine Hepburn  12       0.006407
657     1938    Best Actress    1.0 Bette Davis        10       0.005339
```

Comment: when you execute `df.groupby('Name')` - how should Pandas know what do you want to do with all columns except the "groupping" column -
 `Name`? Can you post your desired data set?

Comment: I think you should use `df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name')`

Comment: @MaxU - Edited to show desired data set. Should I infer from your comment though that if I have more than 2 columns, I have to tell groupby what to do with all of the columns, or drop all of the unnecessary columns?

Comment: In this case you can simply use [DataFrame.drop_duplicates](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) as COLDSPEED proposed...

Comment: Edited the title to be more canonical for future readers. Hope that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your edit, I think you need [`df.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
In [352]: df_revised = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Name'); df_revised
Out[352]: 
   Year         Award  Winner          Name  Winner_Count  Winner_Pct
0  2011  Best Actress     1.0  Meryl Streep            19    0.010144
```

It retains the first row and drops all the rest of the duplicates. This works fine if your data is sorted by year.

If not, sort it first with [`df.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
In [358]: df.sort_values(by=['Name', 'Year'], ascending=False, inplace=True)
```

Comment: df_revised = df.drop_duplicates('Name') -- seems to have worked beautifully, retaining the sort on Winner_Count. Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan Much appreciated, added that in. Also, no probs :)

Answer (score 0):

If you just type `df_new = df.groupby('Name')`, it will give you a groupby object. We have to use an aggregate function after groupby such as `.sum()`, `.mean()`, or etc.

However, it looks like you want to drop the duplication of the name column. What you can do is use `drop_duplicates` like `df_new = df.drop_duplicates('Name')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `max` for the awards won.

```
df.groupBy("Name").max("winner_count")
```